# Make argument optional using <Void> type?

Tags: java

Say I have this interface:

```
  public interface IAsyncCallback<T, E> {
    void done(E e, T v);
  }
```

in a certain case, I want someone to be able to use:

```
IAsyncCallback<Void,Object> cb = e -> {};
```

such that it's clear that they shouldn't expect a second argument (the second argument `v` would always be null.

Is this possible somehow? Having a bit of trouble reconciling 2 argument and 1 argument methods so they can be interchangeable.

Basically would like to find a way to use optional arguments using generics, but I would be curious if there is a way to do this another way, since the above technique won't work, it expects 2 arguments, you can't ignore an argument, etc.

As an aside, if I have an interface like this:

```
  public interface IEachCallback<T, E> {
    void done(E e);
  }
```

I was hoping you could cast either `IAsyncCallback` to `IEachCallback` or vice versa, maybe you can? Seems like you should be able to cast a method that takes a superset of the arguments of another method.

Comment: I tried `Optional<Void>` as well as `Void`, same thing, 2 arguments are required

Comment: All types are at least an `Object` so I think the best you could do is just pass a static pre-made `Object`... the equivalent of a null basically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a native way to make this easy.

One workaround can be to implement `IEachCallback` using default methods in the `IEachCallback` interface and allow users to pass single-argument lambdas:

```
public interface IEachCallback<T, E> extends IAsyncCallback<T, E> {

    @Override
    default void done(E e, T t) {
        this.done(t);
    }

    void done(T e);
}
```

This allows the caller to pass a single-argument lambda, but it still poses the problem of assignment:

```
//there's no way to assign or pass as argument directly
//Otherwise users have to do this type cast:
IAsyncCallback<Void,Object> cb = (IEachCallback<Void, Object>) e -> {};
```

To go around this, I'd add a static factory method to `IEachCallback`:

```
public interface IEachCallback<E> extends IAsyncCallback<Void, E> {

    @Override
    default void done(E e, Void t) {
        this.done(e);
    }

    void done(E e);

    static <E> IAsyncCallback<Void, E> ofVoid(IEachCallback<E> callback) {
        return (e, v) -> callback.done(e);
    }
}
```

And that allows users to call it in a much simpler way:

```
IAsyncCallback<Void,Object> cb = IEachCallback.ofVoid( e -> {});
```

---

For even further improvement, you may want to move this to the parent interface, and eliminate the child interface altogether:

```
public interface IAsyncCallback<T, E> {
    void done(E e, T v);

    static <E> IAsyncCallback<Void, E> ofConsumer(Consumer<E> callback) {
        return (t, e) -> callback.accept(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: that first technique the other interface and use a default method is killer, thanks, although I am not sure what would happen if you use `cb::done`, who knows.

Comment: @AlexanderMills You can use that method reference, as long as it is compatible with the interface. Compatible method references are pretty much interchangeable with lambdas

Comment: Yeah I meant I don't know which `done` method it would bind to, the default done method or the abstract one

Comment: Oh I see. You can only make a method reference linked to one abstract method `done`. So depending on which interface is implemented by it, either of the two abstract methods will be matched (there's only one abstract method signature by interface here)